# Lead time Calc Android and joda

Tags: android

This app takes todays date adds a number of weeks that the user has entered in the text box and displays it. I created this in java console app and it works great, but android is another story... Below is my code thank you. I am having issues parsing the date so android is happy. I do not have any errors it just force closes on me.

thank you.

```
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {

           EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            int value = Integer.parseInt(editText.toString()); 


             DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(); 

             Context context = getApplicationContext();
             CharSequence text = (dateTime.plusWeeks(value).toString("EEEE MM/dd/yyyy"));


             int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
             Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
             toast.show();

        }


    });


}
```

Comment: If you get a force close then logcat will provide more details. Please give us the stack trace.

Comment: 02-19 12:59:19.266: E/dalvikvm(423): Could not find class 'org.joda.time.DateTime', referenced from method com.summeylabs.java.LeadTimeCalcMobileActivity$1.onClick
02-19 12:59:19.266: W/dalvikvm(423): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 23 (Lorg/joda/time/DateTime;) in Lcom/summeylabs/java/LeadTimeCalcMobileActivity$1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider enclosing the call to Integer.parseInt inside a try/catch block. This would make your program more robust.

Answer (score 0):

you should add JodaTime to your project. If you use eclipse, add it as jar librairy. If you use ant, add it to your libs folder. If you use maven add it has a dependency.

Comment: I thought i did this i will see why this is stating no class.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by adding JodaTime to my project. JodaTime is a big time saver if you are working with time in your java app. more info can be found here http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html